# How to unpack a Julia struct entirely into local variables?

Tags: struct, julia, metaprogramming

I have created a complex computational model with lots of parameters. Since I need to run many scenarios, I have decided to wrap all those input parameters into one huge `struct`:

```
using Parameters
@with_kw struct MyModel
    a::Int = 5
    b::Float64 = 5.5
    c::Matrix{Float64} = rand(3,4)
    # 40 other parameters go here
end
```

I have an object `m` for an example:

```
m = MyModel(a=15)
```

Now when writing mathematical code I do not want to write `m.` in front of each symbol. Hence I need to make struct fields into local variables. One way is to to use `@unpack` macro:

```
@unpack a, b, c = m
```

For huge structs that I want to unpack in various functions this is just inconvenient (note that my struct has around 40 fields). How can I unpack the struct without spending time and cluttering my code with all those parameters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The macro `@with_kw` from Parameters.jl defines a macro for this purpose:

```
julia> using Parameters

julia> @with_kw struct MyModel  # exactly as in the question
           a::Int = 5
           b::Float64 = 5.5
           c::Matrix{Float64} = rand(3,4)
           # 40 other parameters go here
       end
MyModel

julia> @macroexpand @unpack_MyModel x
quote
    a = x.a
    b = x.b
    c = x.c
end
```

Thus writing `@unpack_MyModel m` is equivalent to writing `@unpack a, b, c = m`, when you know that `m isa MyModel`.

Comment: Thanks! this indeed saves the time compared to writing macro yourself!

Comment: I guess this is one reason to want the package over `Base.@kwdef struct MyModel`, which does not do this.

Comment: My favorite reason in the nicer visualization for structs when you show them in the console :-)  Anyway `?@with_kw` does not state that this nice macro gets implemented.

Answer (score 2):

For custom cases, you can make a dedicated macro for your type, for other cases see the answers above:

```
macro unpack_MyModel(q)
    code =  Expr(:block, [ :($field = $q.$field) for field in fieldnames(MyModel) ]...)
    esc(code)
end
```

This simply inserts the following code:

```
julia> @macroexpand @unpack_MyModel(m)
quote
    a = m.a
    b = m.b
    c = m.c
end
```

This macro can be used inside of any function such as:

```
function f(m::MyModel)
    @unpack_MyModel(m)
    return a+b
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is [StaticModules.jl](https://github.com/MasonProtter/StaticModules.jl). Here's an example that I copied and pasted from the README for that package:

```
julia> struct Bar
           a
           b
       end

julia> @with Bar(1, 2) begin
           a^2, b^2
       end
(1, 4)
```

Comment: Usually my computational codes are quite big and often contain other macro calls (eg. because of using JuMP). I wonder how robust is `@with` with regards to complex code blocks.

Comment: Good question. I haven't actually used StaticModules.jl myself. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a much more idiomatic approach that doesn't require macros or any other packages. The documentation suggests the most idiomatic approach, for instance the docs for [Matrix factorization](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/LinearAlgebra/#LinearAlgebra.LU).

In particular, this line:

```
julia> l, u, p = lu(A); # destructuring via iteration
```

which suggests iteration is the right way to go. So all that is left is to make your struct implement the [iteration interface](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/interfaces/#man-interface-iteration)

### A really simple but un-idiomatic example:

Your struct looks like this

```
struct MyModel
    a::Int = 5
    b::Float64 = 5.5
    c::Matrix{Float64} = rand(3,4)
    # 40 other parameters go here
end
```

To implement the iteration interface you need to define `Base.iterate` which takes `MyModel` as a parameter and a "state". That function returns the element that corresponds to the state, and calls the next iteration (sort of like a linked list). For example:

```
function Base.iterate(m::MyModel, state)
    if state == 1
        return(m.a, state+1)
    elseif state == 2
        return(m.b, state+1
    elseif state == 3
        return(m.c, state+1)
    else
        return nothing
    end
end
```

In julia an iteration stops when `next(iter) == nothing`, that's why you have to return `nothing` when there is nothing left to iterate over.

### Advanced example

You can find a much more idiomatic (but contrived) example in the [source code](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/0e5fc4cde322eb16f4403574d99fd46840244f91/stdlib/LinearAlgebra/src/lu.jl) for the `lu` factorization:

```
# iteration for destructuring into components
Base.iterate(S::LU) = (S.L, Val(:U))
Base.iterate(S::LU, ::Val{:U}) = (S.U, Val(:p))
Base.iterate(S::LU, ::Val{:p}) = (S.p, Val(:done))
Base.iterate(S::LU, ::Val{:done}) = nothing
```

which uses `Val` for some compile-time optimizations if I'm not mistaken.

In the particular case of a struct with 40 fields I can't think of a more ergonomic way, maybe the data is better suited for another storage option.